# Hbase region requests not balance

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I use this TTL to create table:

```
create "aos:for_test", {NAME => "data", COMPRESSION => "LZO"}, {NUMREGIONS => 240, SPLITALGO => "UniformSplit"}
```

And import a big data file (near 14G) to the table. Even though there are 240 regions for the table, the client report error like follows:

> Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1822 actions: RegionTooBusyException: 1822 times

I check the hbase webUI and find all the requests are hit only one region. I can not figure out why the write request is not balance to all the regions.

However, If I change the TTL like this:

```
create "aos:for_test", {NAME => "data", COMPRESSION => "LZO"}, {SPLITS => ['00000','00001','00002','00003','00004','00005','00006','00007','00008','00009','00009p','00009q','00009r','00009s']}
```

Everything is working.

Comment: What is the region split policy configured ? If it is ConstantSizeRegionSplitPolicy then all the requests will go to the same region until is reaches threshold size.

Comment: I didn't configure the policy. I have no idea what is the default value.

Comment: from HBase 0.94+, Default region spilt policy is IncreasingToUpperBoundRegionSplitPolicy.  Please verify hbase.hregion.max.filesize property value in hbase-site.xml. For more details, please refer http://hortonworks.com/blog/apache-hbase-region-splitting-and-merging/

Comment: The hbase.hregion.max.filesize is 512M,  and memstore.flush.size is 64M, I check the reginserver log,  which have many info like "[B.defaultRpcServer.handler=33,queue=3,port=60020] regionserver.MemStoreFlusher: Blocking updates on datanodetest01.hadoop.ebj.elong.com,60020,1445242980310: the global memstore size 358.0 M is >= than blocking 355.6 M size". Also, from UI I can see the table is keep doing major compact.

Comment: I have read the document. There is a sentence like "Regardless of the method you chose to create the table with pre determined number of regions, you can now start loading the data into the table, and see that the load is distributed throughout your cluster." while I still puzzled...

Comment: OK. Looks like your writes are getting blocked. what is the configuration value for hbase.hregion.memstore.block.multiplier and hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.upperLimit

Comment: Err, I also have not config those two params.

Comment: I think the core issue is why all the write process load on only one region when use the first TTL?

Answer (score 0):

You have two variants of solving problem.

First modify raw key that it will be a randomly distributed across regions. If can be done by taking hash (e.g. md5 vs murmur hash function) of you raw key and use a new key composed from hash and value of your old key like this

`byte[] newKye = Bytes.add(hashOfOldKeyBytes, oldKeyBytes)`.

Second varian, take random 1% of your data and calculate a key distribution base on it. Then based on this data define a region splits. Below a code snippet to do this on java language.

```
byte[][] keys // key from 1% of data 

Collections.sort(splitList, new Comparator<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(byte[] o1, byte[] o2) {
            return Bytes.compareTo(o1, o2);
        }
    });    

byte[][] splitKeys = new byte[numberOfRegions][];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRegions; i++) {
            splitKeys[i] = keys[(i + 1) * keys.length / (numberOfRegions + 1)];    
 }

 admin.createTable(tableDescriptor, splitKeys);
```